# Is it possible to pass data from fragment to activity using Navigation Component ? If yes then please let me know how

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a scenario where I want to pass data from Fragment to Activity using Navigation component.

Comment: Check docs on google site 
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by using SafeArgs.

Add activity to your navigation graph and add the argument to it.

Now you can use the below code to launch the Activity passing the necessary value.

```
findNavController().navigate(YourFragmentDirections.actionYourFragmentToYourActivity(YourArgument))
```

More details on SafeArgs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args

Answer (score 0):

if the question is possibility pass data from fragment to activity in navigation component, the answer is posibble, you just use `Intent` like usual, and put your data to intent and the use `activity.startActivity({yourIntent})`, but i think is not your real question

Comment: Yes this is the usual way but  I want to send data using Navigation Component